# Stream build and Test logs from GitLab

Tags: apache-kafka, gitlab, streaming, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to stream GitLab CI pipeline logs from GitLab server/Runner to other sources ex: Kafka.
We are interested in build logs and Test logs.
GitLab exposes a job API to get a log file with Job Id (below is the link)

Get Log file via GitLab [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-a-log-file)

What we want is push rather than pull.
There are already [same](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/stream-build-and-test-logs-from-gitlab/45655) or [similar](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/forward-gitlab-cloud-logs-to-aws/45699) questions asked in GitLab Forum regarding the same but are unanswered yet.
Is there some thing out of the box or any recommendation for above use case.